# Vertical projectile motion, finding interersection with moving target

Tags: math, physics, projectile

I am writing an aimbot script for my AI, I am a bit confused about how to get the vertical projectile motion formulas to help me find the time and initial velocity required to fire the projectile at so it hits its target, For the target, I have its velocity and vertical displacement, I thought a Quadratic formula to find the intersection of its displacement over time intersecting with the projectiles displacement over time would be the solution but now I am stuck because I am missing the initial velocity as well as the time, Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: is this a 1D simulation,  only along the _y_-axis? Or is it a 2D projectile, or even a 3D projectile? These are all three different problems.

Comment: Also in these problems, there are constraints on the launch speed, because if you do infinite speed the solution is trivial with a straight line to the target and impact in zero time.

Comment: take a look at [Projectile Aim Prediction with Target Acceleration and Bullet Deceleration Varying with Angle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71817221/2521214) for some inspiration

Answer (score 0):

Orient your coordinate plane such that the y-axis is up/down from your perspective, and the z-axis passes through you and your target (+ being towards the target). We do not care about x. Center the origin on you.

We need to first talk about finding the time it takes a projectile to travel from you to the target. Assuming there's no air drag, the projectile will move at a constant velocity along the z axis (it may accelerate along the y-axis, however). This gives us:

```
df_pz = a_pz * t**2 / 2 + vi_pz * t + di_pz

df_pz : final displacement   - projectile's z component
di_pz : initial displacement - projectile's z component
a_pz  : acceleration         - projectile's z component
vi_pz : initial velocity     - projectile's z component
t     : time
```

If we assume there's no air resistance, `a_pz` is zero, and since the origin is centered on you, `di_pz` is zero. That leaves:

```
df_pz = vi_pz * t
```

We know `df_pz` is the distance to the target along the z-axis, and can solve for time `t` for the projectile to travel there. `t` will be defined in terms of `vi_pz`, which is fine.

Now, lets talk about your target's motion. Your target will follow a trajectory:

```
df_ty = a_ty * t**2 / 2 + vi_ty * t + di_ty

df_ty : final displacement   - target's y component
di_ty : initial displacement - target's y component
a_ty  : acceleration         - target's y component
vi_ty : initial velocity     - target's y component
t     : time
```

We know `t` however (or, have an equation we can substitute in anyways), so we can plug in and solve for the final displacement (in terms of `vi_pz`).

With the `df_ty` value, we can now determine the initial y velocity of the projectile. We'll be using a similar formula:

```
df_py = a_py * t**2 / 2 + vi_py * t + di_py

df_py : final displacement   - projectile's y component
di_py : initial displacement - projectile's y component
a_py  : acceleration         - projectile's y component
vi_py : initial velocity     - projectile's y component
t     : time
```

We have time `t`, the `a_py` may or may not be equal to `a_ty`, depending on the game engine, but I'll assume you know that value regardless. We know `di_py` is zero since we're centered at the origin. That just leaves `vi_py` and `df_py`. Since we want to intercept the target, `df_py` equals `df_ty`.

We then plug in those values and solve for `vi_py`. This gives us the initial velocity of the projectile along the y axis, in terms of `vi_pz`.

Now, with this newest equation, we'll actually solve for `vi_py` and `vi_pz`. Take the equation:

```
|V|**2 = vi_py**2 + vi_pz**2

|V| - magnitude of the initial velocity vector
```

The value `|V|` should be constant for any shot (assuming you can't "charge" you shot to shoot the projectile faster / further).

Take whatever this value is, substitute the value for `vi_py` (defined in terms of `vi_pz`) and solve for `vi_pz`. This will give you a concrete value for `vi_pz`. Take this, plug it back into the equation for `vi_py`, and obtain a concrete value for `vi_py`. Do the same for `t`.

Now, there may be one issue- `df_ty` we used earlier may be wrong. If `df_ty` is so low that it places the target below the ground, we need to clamp it to ground-level. Plug in `vi_pz` and check. This is just a simple if statement, I won't be writing a formula for this. You do need to know what y coordinate is "ground-level" below the target.

If this happens, also recompute a new `vi_py`, `vi_pz`, and `t` using this new `df_ty`. The process will be much the same, except you already have a concrete value for `df_ty` now, so you can skip the part involving `|V|` to get `vi_py`.

And there you have it: `vi_py`, `vi_pz`, and `t` - the velocity and time necessary to intercept the target. You may have to take this one step further and calculate the angle to shoot at, which would just be `arctan(vi_py/vi_pz)`.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the time *t*<sub>min</sub> where the missile and target are at the closest approach is fairly straightforward.

Consider at the time of launch *t*=0 the target missile is at the origin, with an initial velocity vector **v** and being tracked as a function of time as

**p**(*t*) = **v** *t* + 0.5 **g** *t*<sup>2</sup>

where **g** is the gravity vector (usually pointing downwards).

At the time of launch, the target is at position vector **o**, moving with velocity vector **u** and being tracked over time with

**r**(*t*) = **o** + **u** *t* + 0.5 **g** *t*<sup>2</sup>

The time of minimum distance is

*t*<sub>min</sub> = (**o**·(**v**-**u**)) / ((**v**-**u**)·(**v**-**u**))

Here · is the vector dot product and it results in a number.So both the numerator and denominators are numbers.

The closest approach distance is

*d*<sub>min</sub> = √( (**o**·**o**) - (**o**·(**v**-**u**))<sup>2</sup> / ((**v**-**u**)·(**v**-**u**)) )

The next part is harder. To optimize the problem, in order to make the minimum distance zero, and find the velocity vector that fits the constraints (max. speed, or time to impact).

The insight here is that the launch velocity vector must be on the plane defined by the target velocity vector and gravity. The simplest approach here is to employ a numerical method to estimate the minimum distance as a function of the launch angle if the launch speed is fixed.

There is an analytical solution here but is very complex and it depends on some assumptions.

Furthermore, once the optimal trajectory is found, you can play around to see which launch speed works best. With some random testing I did I noticed the required speed at the optimal angle as a function of a delay from detection jumps to a really high value at some point, and then gradually decreases. I suppose this corresponds to the time the target is mostly overhead. Optimally you want to detect the target as early as possible.

Comment: @ThomasHawkeBuffler - I have verified numerically the minimum time calculation is correct. Finding the optimal **v** is somewhat more complex.